# NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegException: ' (exit code: -1073741515)'

Tags: c#, nreco

I am able to use the FFMpegConverter() in an ASP.NET Core application in my local environment, but when I use the production server I get the error:

> NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegException: ' (exit code: -1073741515)'

I have tried a lot of stuff with no success. What could cause this issue?

Comment: probably has something to do with the path of the file, but without nay code I can't tell you more...

Comment: var ffMpeg = new FFMpegConverter();
License.SetLicenseKey(_ffMpegKey, _ffMpegValue);
               
ffMpeg.FFMpegToolPath = _hostingEnv.WebRootPath + "\\FfmpegExe";

ConcatSettings _concatSettings = new ConcatSettings();

var _fileNames = filesNames.ToArray();
_newFileName = $"{filesPath}{_keyFile}{_fileExtension}";
string _concatFormat = _fileExtension.Replace(".", "").ToLower();
ffMpeg.ConcatMedia(_fileNames, _newFileName, _concatFormat, _concatSettings);

Comment: @BudaGavril _hostingEnv.WebRootPath points to wwwroot folder, where inside FfmpegExe folder I have ffmpeg.exe file.

I works in dev, but in prod servers does not work, even though I am using visual studio just like in dev env.

Comment: @BudaGavril also, the _newFileName is not just the file name, but the full path (including the name) of the file where the merged file will be stored.

Example: D:\Ervis\TGSBilling\TGS.Web\temp-aws-upload-video-files\09b1f3cd4a51422b9af71b030637a4f7\0f4b96c6180b4e48b606b6e53c568933.mp4

Comment: and do you have the rights in the production environment to run the executable?

Comment: -1073741515 == 0xC0000135 == STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND, you forgot to copy a DLL.  If you don't know which one and a utility like Process Monitor doesn't tell you either then ask the product owner for deployment instructions.

Comment: @BudaGavril I have assinged all permissions to the user I am using

Comment: @HansPassant I am actually using the ffmpeg.exe file as suggested in the documentation of https://www.nrecosite.com/.
I am wondering what I should check to make sure that I can run executable files.

Comment: @HansPassant I know which DLL might cause the issue. Where should I put the DLL in that case?

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you use [NReco.VideoConverter.LT](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.VideoConverter.LT/) nuget package that does NOT include ffmpeg executable (it should be deployed / installed separately).

Exception with a message like "(exit code: -1073741515)" usually occurs when ffmpeg process cannot be started (or crushed) when executed with System.Diagnostics.Process API. Typical reason is wrong executable (say, 64-bit ffmpeg.exe on 32-bit Windows). To ensure that ffmpeg.exe works on your environment it is enough to run it in the command line.

Comment: I am using NReco.VideoConverter.LT nuget package. I have downloaded a ffmpeg.exe file which I use in my machine which is 64-bit windows. 
Is there any 32-bit executable available?

Comment: My prod evnrionemtn seems to be a 64-bit Windows as well. Windows Server R2 2008 Datacenter

Comment: You need to ensure that 'ffmpeg.exe' works on your server in the command line. Official ffmpeg binaries are here: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html